# r data.table grep error with large file but not with example

Tags: r, datatable

I want to search through a specified set of columns in a data.table for a given string and set the value of a different column in the rows that are found.

Here's the basic structure that works fine with this small file.

```
dt <- structure(list(Abstract = c("RCP", "RCP8.5", "Another string"
), Author.Keywords = c("Random key words", "", "Crop system; Environmental sustainability"), RCP = c("None", "None", "None")), class = c("data.table", 
 "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -3L))
```

In the data table, grep looks for "RCP" in the columns Abstract and Author.Keywords and when it finds RCP, it writes "RCP" into the RCP column.

```
dt[grep("RCP", c(Abstract, Author.Keywords), perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE), RCP := "RCP"]
```

But I have a data table called 'livestock with 1,632 rows and 34 columns. This is the message I get when I try to run the same code.

```
livestock[grep("RCP", c(Abstract, Author.Keywords), perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE), RCP := "RCP"]

Error in `[.data.table`(livestock, grep("RCP", c(Abstract, Author.Keywords),  : 
  i[16] is 1825 which is out of range [1,nrow=1632]
```

It appears that my grep code searches beyond the end of the data.table but why? And how to fix?

Using `grepl` instead of `grep` returns

```
Error in `[.data.table`(livestock, grepl("RCP", c(Abstract, Author.Keywords),  : 
  i evaluates to a logical vector length 3264 but there are 1632 rows. Recycling of logical i is no longer allowed as it hides more bugs than is worth the rare convenience. Explicitly use rep(...,length=.N) if you really need to recycle.
```

Comment: Here, the `grep` is applied on multiple column.  Perhaps `i1 <- livestock[, Reduce("|", lapply(.SD, function(x) grepl("RCP", x))), .SDcols = c("Abstract", "Author.Keywords")]; livestock[i1, RCP := "RCP"]`

Comment: This works, which is the key point! But I'm trying to figure out the logic. I haven't used Reduce much. Here's my word interpretation of the first line. For each of the SD cols grepl the search phrase, then use 'or' (|) to set the value of i1 to TRUE if the phrase is in either of the two columns. Is this correct? How would you modify this to use AND; ie the phrase has to be in both?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We specify the columns of interest in `.SDcols`, loop through the Subset of Datatable (`.SD`) with `lapply`, check for the string "RCP" with `grepl` to return a `list` of logical vectors, that is `Reduce`d to a single logical `vector` with `|` (`or`)

```
i1 <- livestock[, Reduce("|", lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     grepl("RCP", x))), .SDcols = c("Abstract", "Author.Keywords")]
```

If the substring "RCP" needs to be in all the columns specified in `.SDcols`, then use `&` instead of `|` in `Reduce`

```
i1 <- livestock[, Reduce("&", lapply(.SD, function(x) 
     grepl("RCP", x))), .SDcols = c("Abstract", "Author.Keywords")]
```

Use the logical vector in `i` to subset the rows and assign the "RCP" to `RCP` column

```
livestock[i1, RCP := "RCP"]
```

Comment: Trying to think of a clever way to do it all in `i` conveniently - maybe `dt[Reduce(\`|\`, lapply(mget(c("Abstract","Author.Keywords")), grepl, pattern="RCP")), RCP := "RCP"]` - a bit awkward though.

Comment: This should probably be a new question but it has similarities to the above. I want to select a subset of the rows by searching across multiple columns. Define grepString as `"(?=.*Sustainable)|(?=.*SDG)"`. Then use this code - `temp <- dt[grep(grepString, c(Abstract, Author.Keywords), perl = TRUE, ignore.case = TRUE),]`. It seems to work but is very slow. Is there an `apply` structure that would work?

Comment: @JerryN  I guess you can use the same syntax by replacing `grepl("RCP"` with `grepl(grepString,`